# Using enum to filter options in subsequent enum as function parameter

Tags: swift, enums

I'd like to use 2 enums to control what options are available when using the below client.

Essentially if `APIService` is `.identity` then `APIEndpoints` should only return endpoints on that service. In this case, `.accessToken`.

I'm not even sure this is possible, if it is however, how could I achieve such a thing?

```
import UIKit

struct MyModel: Codable {
    let id: String
}

enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case error(String)
}

protocol ServiceType {}

protocol EndpointType {
    var baseURL: String { get }
    var path: String { get }
}

// MARK: - APIEndpoints

enum APIEndpoints {
    // MARK: - Profile

    case userProfile(userId: String)

    // MARK: - Identity

    case accessToken(company: String, code: String)
}

extension APIEndpoints: EndpointType {
    var baseURL: String {
        switch self {
        case .userProfile:
            return "https://profile.foo.bar"
        case .accessToken:
            return "https://identity.foo.bar"
        }
    }

    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .userProfile(let userId):
            return "/profile/\(userId)/something"
        case .accessToken(let props):
            return "/auth/realms/\(props.company)/protocol/openid-connect/token"
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - APIService

enum APIService {
    case profile
    case identity
}

extension APIService: ServiceType {}

// MARK: - Client

protocol ClientType {
    func request(forService service: APIService, onEndpoint endpoint: APIEndpoints, completion: @escaping (Result<MyModel>) -> Void)
}

class Client: ClientType {
    func request(forService service: APIService, onEndpoint endpoint: APIEndpoints, completion: @escaping (Result<MyModel>) -> Void) {
        let responseResult = Bool.random()
        if responseResult {
            guard let data = "{\"id\":\"1234\"}".data(using: .utf8), let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MyModel.self, from: data) else { return completion(.error("Decoder Error")) }
            completion(.success(value))
        } else {
            completion(.error("Foo"))
        }
    }
}

let client = Client()

client.request(forService: .identity, onEndpoint: .accessToken(company: "foobar", code: "123")) { response in
    switch response {
    case .success(let values):
        print("do something with \(values.id)")
    case .error(let error):
        print("do something with an error of type \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to encore exactly? Do you want that for example a `request` which takes an `.identity` as service can only have `.accessToken(...)` as endpoint and NOT a `userProfile(...)`?

Comment: Yes that is exactly the setup I am looking for

Comment: Ok, this exact behavior is not possible. Maybe you can provide a more "complicated" example (especially with more `APIService` cases and `APIEndpoints` cases) since it seems in this case that you just have to pass in an "endpoint" and you directly know the corresponding `APIService`.         PS: I would rename `APIEndpoints` to `APIEndpoint` (singular) since the actual value of such a type is only ONE endpoint.